# Matplotlib - dots won't show up, but lines will

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtual-machine, x11-forwarding

I have run into a bizarre issue with Matplotlib.

If I run the following commands, no points are plotted:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10), 'r.')
plt.show()
```

However, if I instead change the marker style to line as follows, then it works just fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

I'm working on a Macbook, but I'm connecting to my Ubuntu Server VM via ssh -X when running this code. I've never had this issue before with other VMs. Any ideas?

Comment: Strange indeed. Are you working in an interactive shell? And the figure window comes through to your display fine, it just doesn't have the dots?

Comment: Providing the MPL, and Python versions would probably be helpful.

Comment: Python version is 2.7.6, matplotlib is 1.4.2. I am working in IPython in the terminal. The figure window shows up just fine, and if I choose a line style the (connected) data points show up fine, but if I try to plot the points individually, the plot window shows up but the points are not there.

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: I can not reproduce this with mpl 1.4.2, python 2.7 installed conda on a linux box.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3711 . Try passing a `markeredgecolor` argument to see if that helps ?